# How to format the output text to a textfile?

Tags: python, text, formatting, format

I have a code running that looks like this:

```
##Prints the latitude and longitude every second.
import time
import microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
    while True:
        data = gps.get_gpgga()
        string=str(data.values())
        text_file = open("/home/pi/fyp/gps.txt","a")
        text_file.write(string + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

This is it's output:

```
dict_values(['', '', '', '0', '', 155641.098, '0', 0.0, '$GPGGA', 0.0, '', '', ''])
dict_values(['', '', '', '0', '', 155642.098, '0', 0.0, '$GPGGA', 0.0, '', '', ''])
dict_values(['', '', '', '0', '', 155643.098, '0', 0.0, '$GPGGA', 0.0, '', '', ''])
dict_values(['', '', '', '0', '', 155644.098, '0', 0.0, '$GPGGA', 0.0, '', '', ''])
dict_values(['', '', '', '0', '', 155645.098, '0', 0.0, '$GPGGA', 0.0, '', '', ''])
```

However, I only need some of the values. 
Namely, the 8th,10th and 13th value (output as '' for now). Is there any way to filter out the rest of the text so I only get this output:

```
'','',''           
'','',''
```

Where the 8th,10th and 13th values are positioned like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `dict_values(...)` to a list and use a list comprehension to access the desired positions.

```
[list(data.values())[x] for x in [7, 9, 12]] # for 8th, 10th and 13th position
```

Comment: Sweet! I got it to work. The output has "[ ]" on them though. Is it possible to remove them and just have the comma seperated values?

Comment: Convert the list to a String and use the join method: 
my_list = [list(data.values())[x] for x in [7, 9, 12]]
my_string = ", ".join(my_list) # or without space if you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found out that I could use string = string[1:-1] after converting the list to a string and it gives me the output I wanted~

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import time
import microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
    while True:
        data = gps.get_gpgga()
        values = data.values()
        string = str(values[7]) + ', ' + str(values[9]) + ', ' + str(values[12])
        text_file = open("/home/pi/fyp/gps.txt","a")
        text_file.write(string + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```